# My email body mess up and break the line and break the words using Ruby on Rails 3 postfix

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.0.6 and have been working on it for the last six months and so. I have configured my mail server postfix and setup it. Now when I send an email it breaks its body, and it inserts a new line where it is not required which break the word. My email contain HTML where sometimes it break the tag and which disturbs the formatting of email as well. I figured out I need to set its default newline option.

I have tested many things, but I am still unable to find a way how to fix this problem.

How can I format my email the proper way?

Comment: Can you post some code here so that we know what exactly you have done? For example, post the e-mail template you use.

Comment: I have resolved the issue actually problem was with mail gem not with my setting, by changing the encoding to 'quoted-printable' from 7bit work for me.

Thanks any ways

Comment: make sure you come back and add your answer and accept it so others can know what the solution is

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the issue. Actually the problem was with the mail gem, not with my setting. By changing the encoding from '7bit' to 'quoted-printable', it worked for me. Actually by default Ruby on Rails 3 set encoding to 7 bits which really disturb the mail format. By changing the following line in mail gem, the problem is resolve.

Change the path to your gem to `/gems/mail-2.2.19/lib/mail/message.rb` and change the encoding type from `7bit` to `quoted-printable`. It will work.

For now, it seem to me it just a hack to my problem, and I am looking for a proper solution that will work with my code. not with gem code.